# TSQL Need to delete an XML node based on a child's value with conditions

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I got an XML like this:

```
<root>
     <child1>
             <...../>
             <...../>
             <...../>
             <child2>
                     <child3>Value1</child3>
                     <child3>Value2</child3>
                     <child3>Value3</child3>
             </child2>
     </child1>
</root>
```

I've been searching for a few days but can't quite find an appropriate answer to this problem I've encountered.

Essentially, I want to delete the node `child1` from the `root` and all its children based on a `value` (In this case, `Value1`) from `child3`, but there may be multiple `child3` nodes and I want to preserve `child3` if it has values I want (In this case, it could be `Value2` or `Value3`), even if it has a value (`Value1`) I'm trying to delete.

Currently, this is what I am using.

```
set @xml.modify('delete root/child1[child2[child3 = "Value1"]]')
```

What I want to do is

```
set @xml.modify('delete root/child1[child2[child3 = "Value1"] AND !(child2[child3 = "Value2"] OR child2[child3 = "Value3"])]')
```

So essentially, Don't delete nodes that have the data in the child that I want, even if it has a specific value I do not want, and then delete the nodes I don't want in every other case.

There are other ways I can do this, by querying an `ID` from the `root` node and doing a ton of prework, but I'd like to make the code as consolidated as possible or otherwise have more intelligent code than that. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you should check the value in the where clause. rather than in the modify . Is this set @xml.modify inside a function or proc?

Comment: Example: Select * From Address AD where AD.Information.Query('root/child1/child2.child3').value('.','varchar(20)') = 'Value1'

Comment: @BobNoobGuy It is in a proc. It loads an XML file into an xml variable, removes the unwanted data (which is this part), uses xQuery to extract and clean the data into temp tables, then writes them to a database for use.

Comment: @Myachizero have you tried solutions from given answers?

Comment: @gofr1 Yes, I apologize. Things happened and I became a bit distracted with some work related things. You actually had the working solution for me, thank you so much!

Comment: @Myachizero my pleasure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [XML.modify()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx) method with [contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178026.aspx) function (`not(contains..)`):

```
DECLARE @x xml = N'<root>
<child1>
    <child2>
        <child3>Value1</child3>
        <child3>Value2</child3>
        <child3>Value3</child3>
    </child2>
</child1>
<child1>
    <child2>
        <child3>Value1</child3>
        <child3>Value4</child3>
        <child3>Value5</child3>
    </child2>
</child1>
<child1>
    <child2>
        <child3>Value5</child3>
        <child3>Value2</child3>
        <child3>Value6</child3>
    </child2>
</child1>
</root>'


SET @x.modify('delete /root/child1[contains(.,"Value1") and (not(contains(.,"Value2")) or not(contains(.,"Value3")))]')

SELECT @x
```

Output will be:

```
<root>
  <child1>
    <child2>
      <child3>Value1</child3>
      <child3>Value2</child3>
      <child3>Value3</child3>
    </child2>
  </child1>
  <child1>
    <child2>
      <child3>Value5</child3>
      <child3>Value2</child3>
      <child3>Value6</child3>
    </child2>
  </child1>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, if I really got this correctly, but you might solve this with a `FLWOR-query()`-cascade:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = 
N'<root>
    <child1 id="1" type="Is to be deleted completely">
        <child2>
            <child3>Value1</child3>
        </child2>
        <child2>
            <child3>Value1</child3>
        </child2>
    </child1>

    <child1 id="2" type="Should remain but those with the search value should be deleted">
        <child2>
            <child3>Value1</child3>
            <child3>Other a</child3>
            <child3>Other c</child3>
        </child2>
    </child1>

    <child1 id="3" type="First child2 delete, second just delete the one with delete value, third untouched">
        <child2>
            <child3>Value1</child3>
        </child2>
        <child2>
            <child3>Value1</child3>
            <child3>Other a</child3>
            <child3>Other c</child3>
        </child2>
        <child2>
            <child3>Other a</child3>
            <child3>Other c</child3>
        </child2>
    </child1>

    <child1 id="4" type="Untouched, no search value">
        <child2>
            <child3>Other m</child3>
        </child2>
        <child2>
            <child3>Other n</child3>
        </child2>
    </child1>
</root>';

DECLARE @DeleteValue NVARCHAR(100)='Value1';
```

- the first FLWOR-query() will rebuild the XML without the nodes carrying the search value
- the second FLWOR-query() will remove all child2 elements with no content
- the third FLWOR-query() will remove all child1 elements with no content

This is the query:

```
SELECT @xml.query
(
N'
<root>
    {
    for $c1 in /root/child1
    return
        <child1> {$c1/@*}
        {
        for $c2 in $c1/child2
        return
            <child2> {$c2/@*}
            {
            for $c3 in $c2/child3[text()!=sql:variable("@DeleteValue")]
            return $c3 
            }
            </child2>
        }
        </child1>
    }
</root>'
).query 
(
N'
<root>
{
    for $c1 in /root/child1
    return
        <child1> {$c1/@*}
        {
        for $c2 in $c1/child2[string-length(.)!=0]
        return $c2 
        }
        </child1>
}
</root>'
).query
(
N'
<root>
{
    for $c1 in /root/child1[string-length(.)!=0]
    return $c1 
}
</root>'
);
```

This is the result

```
<root>
  <child1 id="2" type="Should remain but those with the search value should be deleted">
    <child2>
      <child3>Other a</child3>
      <child3>Other c</child3>
    </child2>
  </child1>
  <child1 id="3" type="First child2 delete, second just delete the one with delete value, third untouched">
    <child2>
      <child3>Other a</child3>
      <child3>Other c</child3>
    </child2>
    <child2>
      <child3>Other a</child3>
      <child3>Other c</child3>
    </child2>
  </child1>
  <child1 id="4" type="Untouched, no search value">
    <child2>
      <child3>Other m</child3>
    </child2>
    <child2>
      <child3>Other n</child3>
    </child2>
  </child1>
</root>
```